# How can one compile libgit2 into an OSX Application Bundle?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, libgit2

The OSX answer to Window's .DLL files is a 'bundle', or so I've been reading, and I can't quite figure out how to get started building libgit2 into something useable.

I normally work on Windows, and am developing a set of plugins that will be used inside [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com/). The plugins, thus far, take the form of Windows .DLL files. However, developers who work in Unity3D on Macs are unable to use the plugin, because it relies on native code built as [libgit2's git2.dll](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2).

According to Unity3D's documentation on [Building Plugins for Desktop Platforms](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html), I need to somehow build a native `bundle`. The instructions point to using XCode to perform the task of setting up a bundle project, however I seem to be getting lost when it comes to how to build it.

Per the documentation on the libgit2 project page, I can use the `CMake GUI` utility to

> [...]generate platform specific build project or IDE workspace

however the XCode project that gets generated does not seem to be a `bundle project`, but rather some sort of other type of project that builds, at least for my purposes, "junk files".

What is the expected format of a bundle as Unity3D describes it?

How can I 'Mix-n-Match' whereby I can build an XCode bundle project, and just drop the needed files from the libgit2 repository in the project, somewhere, and just hit build in order to get the format requested in my previous question?

Comment: Are you building a Mac `.dylib` right now?  You mention that the Mac users can't use `git2.dll` - this is certainly true, you'll need to build a Mac shared library first.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is being built from the default XCode project file generated by CMake, as it seems to be all rubbish. I'll try sifting through and seing if there is a `.dylib` in there somewhere. If I could find that, I'd be able to rename that as a `.bundle`, [per this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23615/how-to-make-unity-find-dylib-files.html) and use it.

Comment: There is.  `libgit2.dylib` should be produced in your build directory.

Comment: Have you tested it with the default CMake build for XCode? Sorry, my VNC locked up, and I'm stuck at work and cannot check at the moment. If you've built the default, and see the `.dylib`, be sure to post your answer so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DLL on Windows is a dynamically library, similar to a `.dylib` on Mac OS.  The CMake rules will create a `.dylib` on Mac OS.

Using the default gcc target:

```
% git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2
% cd libgit2
% mkdir build
% cd build
% cmake ..
% make -j8
% ls -Flas libgit2*.dylib
1348 -rwxr-xr-x  1 ethomson  staff  1379120 Apr  3 16:55 libgit2.0.17.0.dylib*
   4 lrwxr-xr-x  1 ethomson  staff       20 Apr  3 16:55 libgit2.0.dylib@ -> libgit2.0.17.0.dylib
   4 lrwxr-xr-x  1 ethomson  staff       15 Apr  3 16:55 libgit2.dylib@ -> libgit2.0.dylib
```

If you use XCode instead of the gcc/clang target, this should be the directory for the target you're building.  In my case, `Debug`.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I found the library, right where you said it would be. However, Unity still is not recognizing it, even after renaming it. I'm not sure if it's Unity, or `LibGit2Sharp`. At any rate, you did answer my question, and I'll have to figure out some other way to make this all work.

Comment: LibGit2Sharp?  Are you using C#?  Mono?

Comment: I'm using C#. I get an exception when trying to invoke any `LibGit2Sharp` methods -- `System.DLLNotFoundException`. I guess I'm just not sure if the `.dylib` is going to be good enough for this purpose, and I have yet to figure out how to create a proper `bundle`using that generated dynamic library (simply renaming it as another post suggests doesn't seem to be sufficient).

Comment: the libgit2sharp source code in core/nativemethods.cs looks in `Some/Path/NativeBinaries/[amd64|x86]/` for the git2 dll/dylib. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out what `Some/Path/` is!

Comment: On my system, when I dump the local path of the executing assembly from within unity, I get `/path/to/unityproject/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll` which is useless as that's a dir that unity likes to nuke.

Comment: More progress: made nativemethods.cs from libgit2sharp add its full path to the DllNotFoundException. Put libgit2sharp.dll in `UnityProj/Assets/Plugins/Editor` and libgit2.dylib (renamed to git2.dylib as that's what libgit2sharp seems to want) in `UnityProj/Assets/Plugins/Editor/NativeBinaries/x86`. Now I get a nice exception telling me it's looked in the right folder, but it *still* hasn't found the git2 lib.

Comment: ...I even chucked in the git2 dlls from the libgit2sharp repro, just to see if it would load them. Still exceptions.

Comment: last thing: libgit2sharp is preprending the dir it wants to search to the PATH envar. If I dump PATH from unity, the dir's not there. But then maybe it's got a different envar in its dll, I'm not sure.